# javascript:core execution concept

Tags: javascript

```
  function foo(){ alert(this);}
  x=new foo();//this is equal to {foo();}//foo() is operating on the newly created object...
```

Now, according to the definition of this keyword "this points to the current object on which the function operates"

Since the above function operates on the newly created object the this keyword points to it. Now,again:

```
function foo(){
      //this function foo is an javascript object right?

 }
```

So when I create a nested function within it like this,and execute it there itself

```
 function foo(){
 function fo()
      {
       alert(this);//"this" keyword now should point to javascript function object
      }
 fo();//fo here is operating on javascript function object
}
foo();
```

So now when the function `foo()` executes the this keyword should point to the function foo object as per the above definition.

Don't say this: "the value of this keyword depends on how u invoke a function"

I know I'm invoking the function plainly but as per the above definition is my view correct than?

Comment: Your last bit of code is infinitely recursive. It does not call the nested function `fo()`

Answer (score 1):

In your second example the alerted object will be the window. This is because:

1. You are simply invoking the outer function, instead of instantiating it
2. The alerted value is the context of the *inner* function, which is by default the window. The context of the *outer* function would be the instance, if you were using `foo` as a constructor.

To elaborate on the second point, if you were to run the following code, the logged value would be the value of x:

```
 function foo() {
   var that = this;
   function fo() {
     console.log(that); //"this" keyword now should point to javascript function object
   }
   fo(); //fo here is operating on javascript function object
 }
 var x = new foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your view is wrong. Please see my other answer.

Look, if you use `new`, then `this` inside of the scope of the constructor will point to the returned object.

```
var Point2D = function (x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.setX = function (x) { this.x = x; };
    this.setY = function (y) { this.y = y; };
};

var point1 = new Point2D(1, 5),
    point2 = new Point2D(2, 3);

point1.setX(7);
point2.setY(32);
```

My nested functions are set as properties of the ***brand-new "this" which is being created***.

If I had helper functions inside of the constructor:

```
Point2D = function (x, y) {

    function roundX () { return Math.floor(this.x); }
    function roundY () { return Math.floor(this.y); }
}
```

Those functions are ***not added as properties of an object, therefore `this` inside of them calls `window`, instead***.

That is the way JS works.

Either a function is directly a property of an object, or you use `.call()` or `.apply()` to pass the function a different `this`, or the function uses `window`.

Also:

Yes, functions are objects.
But `this` inside of my `Point2D` example doesn't point to the Point2D function...

It points to a brand new object, which gets made and returned.

If you forget to use `new`, guess what gets used as `this`, instead?
`window` does.

There's nothing really magic about it.

When you use a function like my Point2D constructor, there, the function checks if `new` was called.  If it was, then `this = {};` is what happens behind the scenes, at the start of the function. If not, then `this = window` is what is called.

But the same is true for nested functions, as well.
Was `new` used? Then the nested function operates on a 100% brand-new object. Or else, it operates on `window`.

The only 4 ways of getting around that are:

```
function sayName () { console.log(this.name); }

var bob = { name : "Bob" };
```

1) `.call(new_this)`

```
sayName.call(bob); // Bob
```

Proof that functions are objects -- they all have properties/methods of their own

2) `.apply(new_this)`

```
sayName.apply(bob);  // Bob
```

`.apply` and `.call` are the same except for how arguments are passed into the function.

If I used `.call` on Point2D, it would look like:

```
var obj = {},
    x = 1,
    y = 3;

Point2D.call(obj, x, y);
```

Now instead of making a new object, Point2D will do all its work on `obj`.
If I were going to use `.apply` it would look like:

```
var obj = {},
    x = 1,
    y = 3;

Point2D.apply(obj, [x,y]);
```

The whole difference is that you pass an array, instead of one at a time (for cases where you don't know how many arguments there are)

...moving on

3) `.bind` works like the other two, except instead of firing the function, it makes a copy of the function, where `this` ***always*** points to the same object, instead of being calculated every time the function is called.

```
var sayBob = sayName.bind(bob);
sayBob(); // Bob
```

Bind works kind of like this:

```
function bind_this (new_this) {
    var func = this;
    return function () {
        func.call(new_this);
    }
}

function sayName () {
    console.log(this.name);
}

sayName.bind_this = bind_this;

var sayBob = sayName.bind_this(bob);
sayBob(); // Bob
```

There's a little more to it, to get arguments right, but that's the idea.

4) Just setting the function you want to use as a property of the thing you want to use it on...

```
var bob = { name : "Bob" };

function sayName () { console.log(this.name); }

bob.sayName = sayName;
bob.sayName(); // Bob
```

There you have it...
Those are the ways to use `this`

If you use `new` then `this` points to a new object.
If you use `.call` `.apply` `.bind` or set the function as a property of an object, then `this` points at the object you set.

If you don't do either of those things, `this` points at `window`.
It doesn't matter whether the function is nested 6-deep, or if it's in the global scope.  Those are your options.

Imagine that my Point2D looks like this:

```
var Point2D = function (x, y) {
    var this = undefined;
    if (new) { this = {}; }
    else if (called) { this = called; }
    else { this = window; }

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;


    this.setX = function (x) {
        this = undefined;
        if (new) { this = {}; }
        else if (called) { this = called; }
        else { this = window; }
        /* this function is set as a property of another object -- so it is "called", always */
        this.x = x;
        if (new) { return this; }
    };

    this.setY = function (y) { /* same as setX */ };

    if (new) { return this; }
};
```

The internals of all functions, nested or non-nested work like that, under the hood...

So now, looking at that, you should see the differences between these:

```
var obj = {};

var point = new Point2D(1, 3); // new object

var point2 = Point2D(2, 3); // point2 is empty and window gets the values

Point2D.call(obj, 5, 7); // obj is added to, instead of making a new object
```

So now, hopefully you understand the following:

```
var bob = {
    name : "bob",
    speak : function () {
        var name = this.name; // bob
        console.log(name + " is lower case.");

        function uppercase () {
            var window_name = this.name;
            console.log(window_name + " is window.name.");
        }
        uppercase();

        function working_uppercase () { console.log(this.name.toUpperCase()); }

        working_uppercase.call(this);
    }
};
```

If you can't see why this is true, then just take my word for it, and trust that I'm right, and in a couple of years, it will be second-nature to you.

An alternate solution might be to avoid `this` or use it sparingly to avoid confusion.

```
var Point2D = function (x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.findMagnitude = function () {
        return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x
                       + this.y * this.y);
    };
};

var point = Point2D(3, 7);
```

Whoops! There's no `new`.

```
point; // undefined
window.findMagnitude; // function () { ... }
```

So why not deal with functions which don't screw it up, instead?

```
var Point2D = function (x, y) {
    var point = {
        x : x,
        y : y,
        setX : function (x) { this.x = x; },
        setY : function (y) { point.y = y; }
    };

    return point;
};


var point1 = Point2D(1, 3),
    point2 = Point2D(2, 7);
```

I even used `this` on one of the methods, but because I set it directly on the object, as long as I don't copy the function elsewhere or use it in a callback, it's fine.

The other one, I used a reference on... That function can be given to other objects or passed around as a return value, or called asynchronously, and every time, it will do the exact same thing, to the exact same object, because it has a reference to the object, rather than `this`.

Comment: i will get to ur post when i be fresh completely.Thanks a lot for ur post .